# Getting a XML data present in a child node as string using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to convert the XML(Parent XML, FIXML) to String. In that XML one child node is having another XML(Child XML, FpML) data for which I done have schema (xsd). In the schema for the Parent XML, the element type which has the Child XML is defined as String. I need the child XML should come as the string. Please let me know what change I have to do. I am relatively new to JAXB. Thanks in Advance..!!

Cheers,
Sakthi S

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please add the XML document and the JAXB converter you coded so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments:

> Hi.. Thanks for your reply.. @Blaise
>   Doughan & @CoolBeans in the above
>   example you provide you have mentioned
>   String Value but in my
>   xml, instead of "String Value" there
>   will be another XML inside it. like
>   Richard
>   and I need the
>   "Richard" as
>   string in the output. Please let me
>   know still you want more information.
>   Thanks.. Cheers, Sakthi. S

You can use a combination of @XmlAnyElement and a DomHandler implementation to handle this use case.  For a detailed example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

---

**UPDATE #2**

Based on your comments

> Can you please tell me what is change
>   need to be done in the schema to make
>   that filed "@XmlAnyElement", since I
>   am generating the java classes on the
>   build time.

You can use the JAXB `dom` schema annotation to cause an XmlAnyElement to be generated on a property:

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out -b bindings.xml dom.xsd
```

**dom.xsd**

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/default"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/default">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="address"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="address">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="street" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**bindings.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="string.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='customer']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@ref='address']">
                <jxb:dom/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**Customer**

The address property on `Customer` will be annotated with `@XmlAnyElement`:

```
package com.example._default;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "address"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Element address;

    public Element getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Element value) {
        this.address = value;
    }

}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You may be looking for the @XmlValue annotation.  For example if you had the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD
public class Child {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

The above class would marshal to:

```
<child>String Value</child>
```

In the corresponding XML schema the type of the child element would be xs:string.

```
<xs:element name="child" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply.. @Blaise Doughan & @CoolBeans

in the above example you provide you have mentioned 

    <child>String Value</child>

but in my xml, instead of "String Value" there will be another XML inside it. like

    <child><sons><son>Richard</son></sons><child>

and I need the "<sons><son>Richard</son></sons>" as string in the output. Please let me know still you want more information. Thanks..

Cheers,
Sakthi. S

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - Thanks Blaise.. That approach did work.. I need one more favour. In that example the schema related changes are not mentioned. Can you please tell me what is change need to be done in the schema to make that filed "@XmlAnyElement", since I am generating the java classes on the build time. Cheers

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - Blaise, Can you please tell me what is the change need to be done in the schema for this? Cheers

Comment: @Sakthi - I have updated my answer with instructions on how to generate the @XmlAnyElement annotation.  You will need to modify the code to have property be of type String with the corresponding DOMHandler.

Comment: @Blaise - Thanks Blaise. You mean I have to modify the generated Java File or the bindings.xml file?

Comment: @Sakthi - You will need to generate the generated Java file to change the property to type String, and add the DOM Handler to the @XmlAnyElement annotation.

Comment: @Blaise - Thanks Blaise. In the same requirement I am facing another one problem. Using the DOM handler I am able to get the XML inside a tag. But when I marshall (creating the XML) it is giving me SAX exception. In your above example if I want to marshall this ['code'](<names><name>USer</name></names>) inside the customer I am getting the error 
com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it for now with

```
@Column(name="xml")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringXmlAdapter.class)
public String getXml() {
    return this.xml;
}
```

..

```
public class StringXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, String>
{
   private static final String XMLSTART = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";

    @Override
    public Object marshal(String v) throws Exception {

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Document document = ((Node) v).getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document
            .getImplementation();
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        String str = serializer.writeToString((Node) v);
        String normalizedXml = normalizeXml(str);
        return normalizedXml;
    }

    private String normalizeXml(String xml){
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf('>',XMLSTART.length()+1)+1;
        int endIndex = xml.lastIndexOf('<');
        return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

The only problem is that i get

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">
<inner><something>lalala</something></inner></xml>
```

after marshalling

down't know how to erase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string"